# How to fix mobile dropdown from bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[How it should look (Image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPpFg.jpg)

[How it looks on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnMum.png)

Dropdown increases size of navbar on phone version.

Here is a code:

```
<div style=" background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/408H5PI.jpg); background-size: cover; height: 100vh; background-attachment: fixed;">
<div class="sticky d-inline">
<!--Navbar Start-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background: #285123; position: static;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ui7PG0R.png" alt="text bajo" width="50px" height="50px"></img></a>
    
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-expand-lg" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-lg">
        
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown float-right navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-light" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Category
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            {% for Category in category%}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url_for('get_category', id=Category.id)}}">{{Category.name}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </li>

        
      </ul>
    </div>
     
    
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's meant to be like that, it's coming from the `navbar` style.

To prevent it, add `position-absolute` to the `dropdown-menu`, so it won't stretch the parent container, but that will also make the menu stick out of the container, so add  `dropdown-menu-right` as well to keep it within.

(you can tweak it to align left on desktops, and right on mobile with `dropdown-menu-sm-right dropdown-menu-lg-left`)

Try this:

```html
<div style=" background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/408H5PI.jpg); background-size: cover; height: 100vh; background-attachment: fixed;">
<div class="sticky d-inline">
<!--Navbar Start-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background: #285123; position: static;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ui7PG0R.png" alt="text bajo" width="50px" height="50px"></img></a>
    
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-expand-lg" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-lg">
        
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown float-right navbar-expand-lg">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-light" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Category
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu position-absolute dropdown-menu-sm-right dropdown-menu-lg-left" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            {% for Category in category%}
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url_for('get_category', id=Category.id)}}">{{Category.name}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </li>

        
      </ul>
    </div>
     
    
  </nav>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```